# Retrieve BSR and category from string with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

When I parse Amazon products I get this such of string.

```
"#19 in Home Improvements (See top 100)"
```

I figured how to retrieve **BSR number** which is `/#\d*/` 
But have no idea how to retrieve **Category** which is going after `in` and end until brackets `(See top 100)`.

Comment: Try [`/#(\d+)\s+([^(]+?)\s*\(/`](https://regex101.com/r/lX9sT5/1).

Comment: Polish or Russian? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it's return `["#19 in Home Improvements (", "19", "in Home Improvements"]`

Comment: Yes, a whole match, group 1 and group 2. What do you expect? Maybe [`/#(\d+)\s+([^(]+?)\s*\(/`](https://regex101.com/r/lX9sT5/2)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't need word **in**

Comment: Just add `in` - [`/#(\d+)\s+in\s+([^(]+?)\s*\(/`](https://regex101.com/r/lX9sT5/3).

Comment: I find some own solution ` /(#\d+) in (.*)\(.*/ ` which return ` ["#19 in Home Improvements (See top 100)", "#19", "Home Improvements "] ` But in last group I don't need last **space**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```
#(\d+)\s+in\s+([^(]+?)\s*\(
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lX9sT5/3)

```js
var re = /#(\d+)\s+in\s+([^(]+?)\s*\(/; 
var str = '#19 in Home Improvements (See top 100)';
var m = re.exec(str);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1]);
  console.log(m[2]);
}
```

**Pattern details**:

- `#` - a hash
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 capturing 1 or more digits
- `\s+in\s+` - `in` enclosed with 1 or more whitespaces
- `([^(]+?)` - Group 2 capturing 1 or more chars other than `(` as few as possible before th first...
- `\s*\(` - 0+ whitespaces and a literal `(`.

Comment: Note that the lazy `+?` quantifier lets trim Group 2 value with the `\s*` after it. You may use greedy `+`, but you will have to use `trim()` after getting the Group 2 value with the regex.